# Angular 2: Array Concat Method not working

Tags: javascript

In the function below, I am trying to build the filteredProducts array by concatenating the value of the tmp array. The tmp array contains elements but after the concatenation, the filteredProducts array is empty.

Assume the boolean variable refineCriteria.bosch is true;

```
filterProducts(refineCriteria: Refine) {
this.filteredProducts = [];
let tmp = [];

let filtered = false;

if(refineCriteria.bosch) {
  tmp = this.products.filter(product => product.brand == "Bosch");
  this.filteredProducts.concat(tmp);
  filtered = true;      

  console.log("tmp = " + tmp);
  console.log("this.filteredProducts = " + this.filteredProducts);

}


if(!filtered) {
  this.filteredProducts = this.products;
}

console.log("filteredProducts = " + this.filteredProducts); 

this.filteredProductsEvent.emit(this.filteredProducts);
}
```

Comment: `this.filteredProducts = this.filteredProducts.concat(tmp)`

Comment: you need to assign it back to a variable `this.filteredProducts = this.filteredProducts.concat(tmp)`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Marked it as duplicate, since it's not really an Angular question and comments have already answered it